# How to set color of active item in mat-nav-list in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular-material-6

I am new to angular 6 ,here I have a mat-toolbar with mat-sidenav .Everything is working well but I want to set a color for the active item in side nav menu.

currently I have BLACK background I want to set a color when I select the item in the mat-nav-list and also I tried to set mat-divider between each item that also not working .

app.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">

  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)" style="background:black"> //current background is black
    <mat-toolbar class="menuBar">Menus</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a class="menuTextColor" mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a> // want to change the color of the selected item.
      <a class="menuTextColor" mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a> // want to set divider between each item
      <a class="menuTextColor" mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbar">
      <button class="menuTextColor" type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span class="toolbarHeading">Demo App</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: Please **don't** post JavaScript comments in a HTML file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done if you're using Angular Router with the [`routerLinkActive`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) attribute.

From the [documentation for the `RouterLinkActive` directive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive):

> Lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.
>
> **Description**
>
> This directive lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.
>
> Consider the following example:
>
> ```html
> <a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
> ```
>
> When the URL is either `/user` or `/user/bob`, the active-link class will be added to the `<a>` tag. If the URL changes, the class will be removed.

The code below showcases a typical use case:

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">Home</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">Settings</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">About</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

```css
.active-list-item {
  color: #3F51B5 !important; /* Note: You could also use a custom theme */
}
```

A couple of notes:

- You can change `active-list-item` to whatever class name you would like to be applied.
- The `!important` declaration in the second code snippet is used as the list item styles take precedence over your custom styles.

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-router).

Comment: In a modal informational window I have a sidenav and items. Just wondering how to set without routerLink.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

In  Angular Materials 9.0 you have to change color for following class:

```
a.mat-list-item.active { color: #ccc; }
```

Answer (score 1):

hope I'm not too late for this one. I had same problem with `mat-nav-list` and `mat-menu` so with few lines of css I could make it function as I wanted it, try it and see if it fits your needs, scss below:

```
[class^='mat-list-'] {
  &:hover:active {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
  }
  &:focus,
  .mat-list-text {
    background: none !important;
  }
}

[mat-menu-item].is-active,
[mat-list-item].is-active {
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1) !important;
}
```

Now I have custom dark theme so you might want to set colors after your choice.
Just add `routerLinkActive="is-active"` and you are set to go.

/Best regards